# отправить MessageEntity (скрытое сообщение) из теллеграм бота aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу тг бота в aiogram и нужно, чтобы он отправил скрытое сообщение (spoiler)
Как?

```
if m.text == b1:
    await bot.send_message(m.from_user.id, "пошёл бы ты в ...")
```

Comment: Пробовали обернуть текст который вам нужно скрыть в `||`? Вот так: `||текст||`.

Comment: вы забыли `parse_mode='markdownv2'`